# Store pdf from assets to internal storage(private)

Tags: android, storage

In my applications i am having few pdf stored in my assests folder.Now what i want is to copy those pdfs to interal storage (private) asin  (com.android.mypackage).I have written the code but seems not working.I am getting data for path not found

Code

```
private void CopyReadAssets() {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        File file = getDir("Mcq Demo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        try {
            in = assetManager.open("Geography1.pdf");
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

            copyFile(in, out);
            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        File mcqDemo = new File(file, "Geography1.pdf");
        intent.setDataAndType(
                Uri.parse("file://" + mcqDemo),
                "application/pdf");

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you are trying to write a PDF to a directory. That will not work. If you want to write a PDF to a file named `Geography1.pdf`, you need to do so explicitly, with a `FileOutputStream` pointing to such a file.

Second, your `Intent` will not work, as third-party apps have no access to your internal storage.

Comment: So please can you tell me sir how can i do this??

Answer (score 0):

Code for **Copy** File from **assets** to **directory** and Open file

**Variables**

```
public static final String FILE_NAME = "my_file_name";
public final static String FILE_PATH = data/data/Your_Package_Name/";
```

**Method**

```
private void copyFileFromAssets() throws IOException {
    String outFileName = FILE_PATH + FILE_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(FILE_NAME);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myInput.close();
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
   }
```

To **open** PDF file

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File mcqDemo = new File(outFileName);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(mcqDemo), "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```

**Done**